# Is it possible to call a function by onclick with arguments in embedded style javascript in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call the `setVideo()` function on *click* event. But when it is embedded in html, it gets executed right away because of the brackets. Is inline-style the only way to do it?

```html
<script>
window.onload = rv_clicked;
function rv_clicked() {
    var v_links = document.querySelectorAll("#recommendation img");
    for (var i = 0; i < v_links.length; i++) {
        // this gets executed right away:
        v_links[i].onclick = setVideo(v_links[i].title); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using EventListener ? Also Please make your question more clear; where are you calling rv_clicked function()?

Comment: whether it is embedded in html or it is a different script file, the behavior of javascript is same. Post complete thing you are doing.

Comment: When the page is loaded, the function is called.

Comment: In general, if you want to call a function with arguments when an object is clicked. Is it possible to do it in embedded style?

Comment: `something.onevent = function(evt) {doSomething(evt,arg1,arg2);}`...

Comment: Alternatively, in this case, begin your `setVideo` function with `var title = this.title;` since `this` will refer to the element that fired the event, and just use `v_links[i].onclick = setVideo;`.

Comment: But when if the setVideo() function is very long and it is also used by others?

Comment: Oh, I think I can do this.title inside the setVideo() function.

Comment: The problem is what if I don't want to refer to the title of the element that fires the event but the title of something else like its inner element. I am facing another problem now.

Comment: try to write like this, but doesn't seem to work v_links[i].onclick = function () {
                        setVideo(v_links[i].querySelector("img").title);};

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I want the area to be clicked larger and I want to check the title of its inner element.